# Alternative to Canon Printer Software for scanning

Tags: printer, software-rec

I have an Mp980 Canon Printer, which includes a scanner and it came with some software that allows you to scan directly to a PC with out transferring it using USB drive. But the software is big and bulky, and it includes things like printing photo editing and things I can't be bothered with.

Are there any smaller alternatives to this software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VueScan](http://www.hamrick.com/) is one of the best 3rd party scanning utilities available

[ScanTips](http://www.scantips.com/) is an amazing resource for all scanning knowledge

Answer (score 3):

You can just install scanner driver, open Paint, under menu File click on 'From Scanner or Camera...'

[image]

Otherwise you can use IrfanView instead of Paint. http://www.irfanview.com/

Other some info here: http://www.scantips.com/begin2.html

Comment: Paint is brutal, and only saves as bitmap or horribly-compressed JPEG. Use the OS's built-in scanning utilities. http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+image+scanning+site%3Amicrosoft.com

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Windows or a Mac? In both cases the OS will usually recognize a scanner (even as part of a multifunction device) as a scanner, and allow you to use other apps (like ones the OS comes bundled with) to perform scans.

You should install the driver package for the unit first, which is available separately from the bloatware:

http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&tabact=DownloadDetailTabAct&fcategoryid=334&modelid=17357

Pick your OS from the dropdown, and grab the driver package (and leave the bloatware like EasyPhotoPrint on their server where it belongs). Then install just the drivers and use your scanner with the OS-bundled utility (Windows XP, Vista, and 7 all include one, as does Mac OS).

Windows:

> http://www.google.ca/search?q=windows+image+scanning+site%3Amicrosoft.com

Mac OS:

> /Applications/Image Capture.app

Comment: It is wireless and windows oonly recognizes it as a printer, even though it has half a Device Stage. If i use USB then there's a proper Device Stage and I can scan using that.

Comment: @Jonathan: This does not surprise me. Use USB then.

Comment: Well that would mean I have to have my computer switched on when another computer wants to print also the printer is not next to my computer as there isn't room. So there would haveto cables eveywhrre which is one of he reason we bought the printer.